# Is there a better solution?

Tags: ocaml, higher-order-functions

I am making a function that returns the number of times a given number appears in an int list. I have a solution, but I feel it is rather elementary and could be done better (maybe with match and rec??). I also feel the styling is off, but am not too sure how to style OCaml just yet.

Here is the code:

```
let num_occurs (n : int) (nums : int list) : int =
  let x = List.fold_left (+) 0 
  (List.filter (fun (x : int) -> 
  if x = n then true else false) nums) in 
  x / n ;;
```

Comment: I see a potential problem with my solution. If the user inputs a 0 as the int to count, this will not work. I will continue to work on a solution utilizing match.

Comment: Why do you apply x/n at the end?  It seems like you're dividing the count by the number itself...

Comment: Anyway, the right way to do this is probably just List.length (List.filter (fun x -> x = n) nums)  -- or something like that, I'm too lazy to pull open a terminal to check that the syntax is right

Comment: So my solution was very confusing and poor. My plan was to take the int list input, filter out the numbers that didnt match the given ( so if 4 was the number I needed, [1; 2; 3; 4; 4] -> [4; 4]), and then add these numbers using the fold function (that would return 8), then I would divide by the given number (4) to get the number of repetitions (2)

Comment: Ah, that makes sense, yeah.  I see what you were thinking now, that's reasonable, but it can be simplified :)

Comment: Just a quick comment: `if x = n then true else false` is simply `x = n` since this will return `true` or `false`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what you have looks pretty good, though I'm not sure what `x / n` is intended to do.  Using List.fold_left and List.filter is a good intuition for OCaml.  To make this a bit cleaner, though, just use List.length!  As a bonus, you can use x = n directly rather than `if then else`.

```
let num_occurs (n : int) (nums : int list) : int =
  List.length (List.filter (fun x -> x = n) nums)
```

Comment: For reference, this page is where I learn about OCaml List functions: https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/List.html

Answer (score 0):

As noted, `List.fold_left` is a good call, but you're doing more work than you need to. This can be done in one pass by having the accumulator for `List.fold_left` *be the count*.

```
# let num_occurs (n : int) nums =
    List.fold_left (fun i x -> if x = n then i + 1 else i) 0 nums;;
val num_occurs : int -> int list -> int = <fun>
# num_occurs 3 [3; 5; 7; 8; 3; 1; 2; 3];;
- : int = 3
# num_occurs 0 [3; 5; 7; 8; 3; 1; 2; 3];;
- : int = 0
# num_occurs 5 [3; 5; 7; 8; 3; 1; 2; 3];;
- : int = 1
```

We *could* filter `nums` on equality with `n` and then get the length of that list *but* that requires iterating completely over `nums` and building a list of all of the matching elements, and then iterating over that list completely to calculate its length. But we don't care about that list, so better not to do all of that extra work.

Alternatively, a strategy for this is to generate a map of numbers in the list to the number of times they occur. We start out with a module to deal with mappings based on integers.

```
module IntMap = Map.Make (Int)
```

Now, we can fold over our input list building up a map.

```
# let count lst =
    List.fold_left 
      (fun m x -> 
         IntMap.update 
           x 
           (function
            | None -> Some 1 
            | Some c -> Some (c + 1)) 
           m) 
    IntMap.empty 
    lst;;
val count : int list -> int IntMap.t = <fun>
```

Now we just need to use the map lookup functions.

```
# count [3; 5; 7; 8; 3; 1; 2; 3] |> IntMap.bindings;;
- : (int * int) list = [(1, 1); (2, 1); (3, 3); (5, 1); (7, 1); (8, 1)]
# count [3; 5; 7; 8; 3; 1; 2; 3] |> IntMap.find_opt 5;;
- : int option = Some 1
# count [3; 5; 7; 8; 3; 1; 2; 3] |> IntMap.find_opt 0;;
- : int option = None
# count [3; 5; 7; 8; 3; 1; 2; 3] |> IntMap.find_opt 3;;
- : int option = Some 3
```

This approach is particularly beneficial if you need to find the number of occurrences of multiple values in the same list as the info is generated *once* and lookups are O(log n).